# How do I make a mosaic for multiple rtsp streams?

Tags: vlc, rtsp, ip-camera

What I'm trying to achieve is to display 3 ip cameras on VLC at the same time.

Is there a clear, step-by-step guide that anyone can refer me to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a clear, step-by-step guide that anyone can refer me to?

Here's 2:

FFmpeg (which VLC uses internally) https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos

And the VLC one (note different CLI flags) https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Make_a_mosaic/